# Selecting best possible way to filter out specific condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please refer to the below scenario. The database stores 2 kinds of actions done by the user and needs to evaluate which user logged out without interacting with the system.

> Action1 -> User logged in
>
> Action2 -> User presses button

Once the user logged in the database stores Logged status and user ID and if the user presses a button it logged that action as well.

Ex.

Database
Status-------UserID

LoggedIn-----------------123

ButtonPress------------         123

LoggedIn-----------------456

LoggedIn-----------------789

ButtonPress------------         789

ButtonPress------------         789

LoggedIn-----------------111

LoggedIn-----------------456

LoggedIn-----------------123

`ButtonPress` action can occur multiple times but its a must to press the button after Loggedin to the system. User ID 111 only logged in to the system but ButtonPress action is not done. User ID 123 logged in to the system again as the last record. But no `ButtonPress` events found.

How to filter out all the users who didn't go through the `ButtonPress` action.
User IDs 123,111 and 456 should return as the IDs who didn't went through ButtonPress action.

What is the best optimal way to solve this problem??

Comment: how would you `order` these rows?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala There is no specific order.

Comment: user id 456 should also come with 123 and 111, right ?

Comment: @VikasSaini Yes. Sorry for the mistake

Comment: @HarshaW is there any id field in table?

Comment: Yes. Auto Incrementing ID field is there. And also logged date is also there

Comment: @HarshaW given the answer based on your input.

Comment: @VikasSaini Thanks. Ill try it and get back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 
                  from table t1 
                  where t1.userid = t.userid and t1.status = 'ButtonPress'
                 );
```

**EDIT :** If your data has same format that you have provided then you can use `GROUP BY`  :

```
select t.*
from (select userid, sum(case when status = 'LoggedIn' then 1 else 0 end) LoggedIn_c,
             sum(case when status = 'ButtonPress' then 1 else 0 end) ButtonPress_c
      from table t
      group by userid   
     ) t
where LoggedIn_c >= ButtonPress_c;
```

Comment: Thank you. Modified the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Wrong answer in this kind of cases. LoggedIn-----------------123
ButtonPress------------ 123
ButtonPress------------ 123
ButtonPress------------ 123
ButtonPress------------ 123
LoggedIn-----------------456
LoggedIn-----------------789
ButtonPress------------ 789
ButtonPress------------ 789
LoggedIn-----------------111
LoggedIn-----------------456
LoggedIn-----------------123

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
select user_id from 
tablename 
where status!='ButtonPress' and 
id in (select max(id) from tablename GROUP BY user_id) ;
```

Here we are finding latest activity status for each user in subquery and then filtering user which have 'loggedin' status in outer query.